# Trouble creating custom sanitization function when uploading video files

Tags: theme-development, themes, sanitization

I'm trying to create a Theme Customizer control in Wordpress that will allow the user to upload an MP4 and WEBM video, and in doing so I need to create a sanitization option to verify the file type. I'm having some trouble and can still upload any type of file...

Here's what I'm doing:

```
function customizer_header_image( $wp_customize ) {

  // Header Background Video (MP4)
  $wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_video_mp4', array(
    'default'             => '',
    'sanitize_callback'   => 'check_header_video'
  ) );

  $wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Upload_Control( $wp_customize, 'header_video_mp4_control', array(
      'label'             => __( 'Header Video (MP4)', 'rainier' ),
      'section'           => 'header_image',
      'settings'          => 'header_video_mp4',
    ) )
  );

}

// Register the customize functions
add_action( 'customize_register', 'customizer_header_image' );

// Custom sanitize function for header video uploads
function check_header_video($file){
  return validate_file($file, array('webm', 'mp4'));
}
```

As you can see I pass the control's `'sanitize_callback'` parameter to my `check_header_video`, and in there you can see in that function that it runs the file against a native Wordpress function `validate_file`, with accepted file types.

Not having much luck. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`validate_file`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/validate_file) doesn't quite work the way you're expecting it to - it checks if `$file` is in the allowed files array, not just its extension/mime type.

You're looking for [`wp_check_filetype`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_filetype). However, all that ultimately does is check the extension (i.e. it doesn't read the headers of the file/ascertain the mime type otherwise).

Unless you implement your own PHP library for mime checking, it'd be quicker & easier to perform a simple regex check on the filename:

```
return preg_match( '/\.(mpe?g4?|webm)$/', $file ); // Or similar
```